# In C#, how do I process a large text file with multiple threads/tasks, but with conditions?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, task-parallel-library

I am writing a file-processing program in C#. I have a HUGE text file, with 5 columns of data each separated by a bar(|). The first column in each row is a column containing a person's name, and each person has a unique name.

Its a very large text file, so I want to process it concurrently using multiple tasks. But I want every row with the same name to be processed by the **SAME** task, not a different task. For example, if (part of) my file reads:

```
Jason|BMW|354|23|1/1/2000|1:03
Jason|BMW|354|23|1/1/2000|1:03
Jason|BMW|354|23|1/1/2000|1:03
Jason|Acura|354|23|1/1/2000|1:03
Jason|BMW|354|23|1/1/2000|1:03
Jason|BMW|354|23|1/1/2000|1:03
Jason|Hyundai|392|17|1/1/2000|1:06
Mike|Infiniti|335|18|8/24/2005|7:11
Mike|Infiniti|335|18|8/24/2005|7:11
Mike|Infiniti|335|18|8/24/2005|7:11
Mike|Dodge|335|18|8/24/2005|7:18
Mike|Infiniti|335|18|8/24/2005|7:11
Mike|Infiniti|335|18|8/24/2005|7:14
```

Then I want one task processing *ALL* the Jason rows, and another task processing *ALL* the Mike rows. I don't want the first task processing any Mike rows, and conversely I don't want the second task processing any Jason rows. Essentially, how can I make it so that all rows of a certain name are all processed by the **SAME** task? ALSO, how will I know when all the processing of all the rows has  been completed? I've been racking my tiny brain and I can't come up with a solution.

Comment: Just start a few processes. Send each "name" line to the appropriate process.  BTW it's incredibly unlikely you need multiple processes here.  How big is the file?

Comment: It's got a whole lot of lines. I know I probably won't need multiple threads, but my manager wants it done that way. This project im talking about here is kind of like a dummy project that I'm working on myself, and if it works, I can mimic the same logic on my work project. They want it done with multithreading, don't ask me why. I'm a little confused by your proposed solution. Could you show me what you mean with some code, please? I'm a bit of a novice with multithreading.

Comment: Would you be OK with a solution that satisfies the requirement of having a dedicated `Task` per name, that would be considerably slower and less memory-efficient than a sequential (single-thread) approach?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. But I'm not sure how to go about implementing it. As I said, I am very new to multithreading/concurrency, it confuses me at the moment.

Comment: Tasks and multithreading are different concepts... It looks like you really need someone to help with basics of both... There is no way to ask a question on SO to get what you actually need as an answer - reading most voted posts in corresponding tags may be a way to get that knowledge so.

Comment: Has the file been sorted by name?

Comment: How big is the file? What are you going to be doing with the data from the file?

Comment: @AkshayNatu What is "huge"? Gigabytes? Terabytes?

Comment: My suggestion is to start with a non multithreaded solution first. It will be easier to write, and in most cases will be "fast enough". Then add multithreading _if needed_.

Comment: You don't need a queue by name (as some answers have suggested). You need a small number of queues, one per thread, and can hash the name to one of the queues.

Comment: @IanMercer You write trading apps ;) -- this is true, and utilizes resources in a more balanced/efficient way.

Comment: @IanMercer Could you explain more? I don't get it. :(

Comment: @tymtam Basically, think of threads as expensive, because they are, and they are finite. If you had a dedicated thread per unique human name, you'd run out. By coming up with a way to map names to a smaller, limited subset of threads you avoid much context switching and overuse of threads. A hash, or some other algorithm that maps to fewer threads will most likely lead to better throughput. Hashing is one way to do that. You could also "bucket" or "partition" names. For example, everybody that starts with 'A-F' goes here, and everybody that starts with 'G-K' goes there, and so on.

Comment: @Kit All clear. Your explanation made me realise that assumed that there are not many different names in the file (an assumption that is very likely wrong). Thanks!

Comment: IO is much slower than any improvement that you could get with multiple tasks/threads.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for a concurrent dictionary of concurrent queues, keyed by name.

In the main thread (call it the reader), loop line by line enqueueing the lines to the appropriate concurrent queue (call these the worker queues), with creation of the a new worker queue and dedicated task as needed when a new name is encountered.

It would look something like this (note: this is semi-pseudo code and semi-real code and has no error checking, so treat it as a base for a solution, not *the* solution).

```
class FileProcessor
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Worker> workers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Worker>();

    class Worker
    {
        public Worker() => Task = Task.Run(Process);

        private void Process()
        {
            foreach (var row in Queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                if (row.Length == 0) break;
                ProcessRow(row);
            }
        }

        private void ProcessRow(string[] row)
        {
            // your implementation here
        }

        public Task Task { get; }

        public BlockingCollection<string[]> Queue { get; } = new BlockingCollection<string[]>(new ConcurrentQueue<string[]>());
    }

    void ProcessFile(string fileName)
    {
        foreach (var line in GetLinesOfFile(fileName))
        {
            var row = line.Split('|');
            var name = row[0];

            // create worker as needed
            var worker = workers.GetOrAdd(name, x => new Worker());

            // add a row for the worker to work on
            worker.Queue.Add(row);
        }

        // send an empty array to each worker to signal end of input
        foreach (var worker in workers.Values) 
            worker.Queue.Add(new string[0]);

        // now wait for all workers to be done
        Task.WaitAll(workers.Values.Select(x => x.Task).ToArray());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetLinesOfFile(string fileName)
    {
        // this helps limit memory consumption by not loading
        // the whole file at once
        return File.ReadLines(fileName);
    }
}
```

I suggest that your reader thread stream the file rather than reading the entire file; you stated the file was huge, so streaming would be memory friendly). That reader thread *is* I/O bound, so if you can async/await it, that would be better than my simple `Process()` doing a `foreach` with no awaiting.

The features of this approach:

- dedicated task per person's name
- use of a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) value to signal end of input
- use of `Task.WaitAll` to join back to the main thread
- assumes the tasks are CPU bound. If they are I/O bound, consider using async/await and `Task.WhenAll` instead
- file is streamed into memory with [File.ReadLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-5.0)
- names do not need to be sorted because the queue to enqueue to is selected by name on-demand

#### Refinements

In the interest of completeness, the approach above *is* a bit naive and can be refined by... reading all of the comments and answers; users Zoulias and Mercer in particular have good points. We can refine this approach with

- adapt this to TPL Channels and use CompleteAdding. These are not only better abstractions, but more efficient (*abstraction* and *efficient* can often be at odds, but not in this case).
- reduce the name-to-thread or name-to-task dedication, which can exhaust resources in the case of a large number of names, and instead map names to buckets or partitions where each bucket/partition has a dedicated task/thread.

For the second point, for example, you could have

```
// create worker as needed
var worker = workers.GetOrAdd(GetPartitionKey(name), x => new Worker());
```

where `GetPartitionKey()` could be implemented something like

```
private string GetPartitionKey(string name) =>
    name[0] switch
    {
        >= 'a' and <= 'f' => "A thru F bucket",
        >= 'A' and <= 'F' => "A thru F bucket",
        >= 'g' and <= 'k' => "G thru K bucket",
        >= 'G' and <= 'K' => "G thru K bucket",
        _ => "everything else bucket"
    }
```

or whatever algorithm you want to use as a partition selector.

Comment: `File.ReadLines` will stream one line at a time, for what it's worth. Could probably use that in place of `GetLinesOfFile`

Comment: @RufusL Thanks! Didn't know that off the top of my head. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I should have said "it allows you to start enumerating the collection before the whole collection is returned" to be more accurate :)

Comment: Hm, yeah. It's probably wrong for me to say it streams line by line. I'll update my answer again for accuracy purposes. The streaming is likely buffered less granular than a line!

Comment: @AkshayNatu please check my last edit. You have to break out of the worker loop when the sentinel value is received!

Comment: Instead of using a sentinel you could call the [`CompleteAdding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.completeadding) method. But the fundamental problem with this solution is that the `BlockingCollection<T>` class is not asynchronous, so each `Worker` will block a `ThreadPool` thread. Unless the number of unique names is very small, the `ThreadPool` is going to be heavily saturated, almost all of the data will end up in the queues, and processing most names will not start before the reading of the whole file has completed.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias good points, all. The hashing is way more stable, assuming the hash is kind of sort of a *bad* hash. More like bucketing (e.g. on first name letter) than hashing.

Comment: @Kit when you say "That reader thread is I/O bound, so if you can async/await it, that would be better than my simple Process() doing a foreach with no awaiting", do you mean I should have async/await in the Process function or the reader thread?

Comment: The reader thread for sure. That means async/await on the reader "all the way up". For your Process tasks, it depends on if they are themselves I/O bound or not. In my experience you usually have something like this: I/O bound reader, 1+ CPU bound processors, and then a final I/O bound writer or publisher...

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to implement the [producer-consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) pattern, with one producer that reads the file line-by-line, and multiple consumers that process the lines, one consumer per name. Since the number of unique names may be large, it would be impractical to dedicate a `Thread` for each consumer, so the consumers should process the data asynchronously. Each consumer should have its own private queue with data to process. The most efficient asynchronous queue currently available in .NET is the [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) class, and using it as a building block would be a good idea, but I will suggest something higher-level that this: an [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) from the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. This component combines a processor and a queue, is async-enabled, and is highly configurable. So it will make for a succinct, quite readable, and hopefully quite efficient solution:

```
var processors = new Dictionary<string, ActionBlock<string>>();
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
    string name = ExtractName(line); // Reads the first part of the line
    if (!processors.TryGetValue(name, out ActionBlock<string> processor))
    {
        processor = CreateProcessor(name);
        processors.Add(name, processor);
    }
    var accepted = processor.Post(line);
    if (!accepted) break; // The processor has failed
}

// Signal that no more lines will be sent to the processors
foreach (var processor in processors.Values) processor.Complete();

// Aggregate the completion of all processors
Task allCompletions = Task.WhenAll(processors.Values.Select(p => p.Completion));

// Wait for the completion of all processors, and allow errors to propagate
allCompletions.Wait(); // or await allCompletions;

static ActionBlock<string> CreateProcessor(string name)
{
    return new ActionBlock<string>((string line) =>
    {
        // Process the line
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        // Configure the options if the defaults are not optimal
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer too. TPL data flow is a bit more modern, and not having to use a sentinel is nice.

Comment: @Kit the TPL Dataflow is at least [10 years old](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Stephen-Toub-Inside-TPL-Dataflow) now, so it's not exactly cutting edge technology. The [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) is the new kid in town!

Comment: Hm. The decades... the abstractions... LOL

Answer (score 1):

> how can I make it so that all rows of a certain name are all processed by the SAME task?

A `System.Threading.Task` can be created using various [`TaskCreationOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=net-5.0) that dictate how and when their threads and resources are managed during their lifetime. For an operation for consuming large amount of data and furthermore segregating the consumption of data to specific threads - you may want to consider creating the tasks that are responsible for individual names with the option `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` [which may provide a hint to the task scheduler that an additional thread might be required for the task so that it does not block the forward progress of other threads or work items on the local thread-pool queue.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=net-5.0)

For the actual how, I would recommend starting various 'Worker' threads, each with their own `Task` and a way for your main `task` (the one reading the file, or parsing the JSON data) to communicate between the two that more work needs to be completed.

Consider the use of thread-safe collections such as a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0) or [other various collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-5.0) that may help you in streaming data between threads for consumption safely.

Here's a very limited example of the structure you may want to consider:

```cs
void Worker(ConcurrentQueue<string> Queue, CancellationToken Token)
{
    // keep the worker in a 
    while (Token.IsCancellationRequested is false)
    {
        // check to see if the queue has stuff, and consume it
        if (Queue.TryDequeue(out string line))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Consumed Line {line} {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }

        // yield the thread incase other threads have work to do
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished Work");
}

// data could be a reader, list, array anything really
IEnumerable<string> Data()
{
    yield return "JASON";
    yield return "Mike";
    yield return "JASON";
    yield return "Mike";
}

void Reader()
{
    // create some collections to stream the data to other tasks
    ConcurrentQueue<string> Jason = new();
    ConcurrentQueue<string> Mike = new();

    // make sure we have a way to cancel the workers if we need to
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new();

    // start some worker tasks that will consume the data
    Task[] workers = {
        new Task(()=> Worker(Jason, tokenSource.Token), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning),
        new Task(()=> Worker(Mike, tokenSource.Token), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < workers.Length; i++)
    {
        workers[i].Start();
    }

    // iterate the data and send it off to the queues for consumption
    foreach (string line in Data())
    {
        switch (line)
        {
            case "JASON":
                Console.WriteLine($"Sent line to JASON {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                Jason.Enqueue(line);
                break;
            case "Mike":
                Console.WriteLine($"Sent line to Mike {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                Mike.Enqueue(line);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine($"Disposed unknown line {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                break;
        }
    }

    // make sure that worker threads are cancelled if parent task has been cancelled
    try
    {
        // wait for workers to finish by checking collections
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        } while (Jason.IsEmpty is false && Mike.IsEmpty is false);
    }
    finally
    {
        // cancel the worker threads, if they havent already
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}

// make sure we have a way to cancel the reader if we need to
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new();

// start the reader thread
Task[] tasks = { Task.Run(Reader, tokenSource.Token) };

Console.WriteLine("Starting Reader");
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
Console.WriteLine("Finished Reader");

// cleanup the tasks if they are still running some how
tokenSource?.Cancel();

// dispose of IDisposable Object
tokenSource?.Dispose();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: OP claims it's a really large file.  There is probably a lot more users than just Mike and Jason.  Hard coding your queues like that seems problematic.

Comment: Absolutely. The purpose of providing my explicitly simple example was not to provide an entire implementation for the OP,  but to point out some useful features and a general structure they may want to consider while fully implementing their project. I wanted to avoid abstracting the core concept of compartmentalizing workers threads.